# shell commands not recognised when called through ANT

Tags: shell, ant, cygwin, build.xml

I am calling a shell script from ANT build.xml on a windows machine in which I have cygwin installed. The script is getting called and the initial echo statements are being executed in the script. But it is throwing error at statements like 'sed' or 'find' in the script. When I execute the script in cygwin directly it is successfully executed. On when it is called from ANT, it thows error and build fails. I am calling the shell script from build.xml as below:

```
    <target name="xml2prop"
    description="exec shell script"
         >
    <exec dir="." executable="C:\cygwin\bin\bash" osfamily="windows">    
        <arg value="C:\script\testscript.sh"/> 
        <arg value="${root}"/>
    </exec> 
</target>
```

The shell script snippet is as below:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
echo "error"
else
echo "\$1 is \"$1\" and total args to $0 are $# "
rt="${1//\\//}"
echo $rt
fi;
find "$rt" -name "*.xml" | 
while read xmlfile
do
echo "$xmlfile";
done
```

The error that I am getting is as below

```
[exec] $1 is "C:\new\test" and total args to C:\script\testscript.sh are 1
[exec] C:/new/test
[exec] FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

Can you please help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: why don't you echo the find command as a string and see what's being passed to it.

Comment: Some older versions of `find` don't default `-print`, you might try that.  Failing that, put `set -x` at the start of your script to see what values are generated.

Answer (score 1):

What is your path like?  It looks like the script is actually running windows find.exe. In may be good idea to use absolute path to invoke commands

```
FIND_CMD=/bin/find
ANOTHER_COMMAND=/usr/bin/find
//assert find command exists
if [ ! -x $FIND_CMD ]
        echo "not found command "
        exit 1;
fi

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
echo "error"
else
echo "\$1 is \"$1\" and total args to $0 are $# "
rt="${1//\\//}"
echo $rt
fi;
$FIND_CMD "$rt" -name "*.xml" | 
while read xmlfile
do
echo "$xmlfile";
done
```

In general avoid calling platform specific scripts from ant. Writing a java task or a program is far easier.

Comment: thanks Jayan.. most of my commands are working with it "jar" command in my shell script is creating a problem in executing. What should i do for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running the script in the Windows Shell not in Cygwin. In this case you'd be calling the FIND that comes with Windows and get the exact error you are reporting.

I'd look at how you are running your script and make sure that you are calling the proper Cygwin shell to run your script.

Comment: can you please help me figure out if the following is correct way to call cygwin shell from the build.xml on a windows machine to run the shell script ?   
<exec dir="." executable="C:\cygwin\bin\bash"    osfamily="windows">             <arg value="C:\script\testscript.sh"/>          <arg value="${root}"/>     </exec>

Comment: You're calling it correctly. However, as Jayan points out you need to ensure that your PATH has the Cygwin tools first, or that you are using absolute paths in your script.